# Flutter and Getx: How to Pass parameters from UI to Getx controller?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have this Getx controller for reading content of a Post from database:

```
class ReadSinglePostController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var posts = Post(
          postID: 1,
          userID: 0,
          thumbnail: 'thumbnail',
          imageList: 'imageList',
          title: 'title',
          description: 'description',
          createdTime: DateTime.now())
      .obs; //yes this can be accessed

  var postid = 2.obs; //I want this value to change when I click a post in the UI

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    readPost(postid);
  }

  updateID(var postID) {
    postid.value = postID;
    print('im print ${postid.value}');
  }//should update postid when a post is clicked in the UI

  Future readPost(var postID) async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var result = await PostsDatabase.instance.readPost(postID);
      posts.value = result;
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem I'm now facing is that: to read a specific Post from database, I need the `postID` parameter. And as you can imagine, this parameter can be recorded when I click a specific Post in UI, but how do I pass that parameter to this Getx controller? Or maybe I am doing this whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the instance of your controller on the Ui.

For example, on the widget you call the controller:

```
final ReadSinglePostController _controller = Get.put(ReadSinglePostController());

//and when you need to change you do like this:
_controller.updateID(newId);
```

Inside the updateID method you can call the load method:

```
updateID(var postID) {
  postid.value = postID;
  print('im print ${postid.value}');
  readPost(postID);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It works! I have one more quick question though, in your answer, you use `_controller.update(newId)`. I previously used                 `GetX<ReadSinglePostController>(
      builder: (controller) {` in my widget tree. Are these two methods different? and How?

Comment: So there're 3 types of state management on Getx: Gex, Obx and GetBuilder, you can choose which one is better for your needs. I always used Obx cause i think easier and clear. And i feel easier to hear states changes on the widget too. You can read more about the differences here: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#getbuilder-vs-getx-vs-obx-vs-mixinbuilder

Answer (score 3):

For those who may be using obs, you can do as follows:

In the controller, you can define

```
var postid = 0.obs
```

and from the view just add

```
controller.postid.value = 20;
```